# How does MPI allreduce work

Tags: python, mpi, ipython, mpich

I don't have much experience with MPI and I try to understand how allreduce work. Below is a simple example inspired by this [IPython tutorial](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_mpi.html). 2 MPI engines are launched on a local computer from the IPython notebook dasboard here:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
        from IPython.parallel import Client

In [2]: c = Client(profile='mpi')

In [3]: view = c[:]

In [4]: view.scatter('a', np.arange(4.))
Out[4]: <AsyncResult: scatter>

In [5]: %%px
        from mpi4py import MPI
        import numpy as np

        print MPI.COMM_WORLD.allreduce(np.sum(a), op=MPI.SUM)
[stdout:0] 1.0
[stdout:1] 5.0
```

I would have expected each engine to print "6.0", like in the IPython tutorial. Here, it is as if the reduction operation was not performed. It's probably very simple, but I don't quite see what I am doing wrong?

I use:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Python 2.7.3 32-bit
- IPython 1.1.0
- mpi4py 1.2.2
- mpich2

Comment: I wonder if, unlike the python tutorial, the fact you are using allrecude (lowercase-a) whereas they use Allreduce (upper-case a) matters?

Comment: Using Allreduce leads to the exact same problem. I use allreduce here just to make the example shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the behavior you would see if your engines were not actually started with MPI. Since your engines have no MPI peers, allreduce doesn't do anything - it just returns the value of `np.sum(a)` on each engine, which is what you are seeing.

It's a good idea to check that MPI is set up properly:

```
%px print MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank(), MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
```

If your engines are not in the same MPI world, your output will look like this:

```
[stdout:0] 0 1
[stdout:1] 0 1
```

And if they are:

```
[stdout:0] 0 2
[stdout:1] 1 2
```

Make sure you start your engines with MPI. For example:

```
ipcluster start --engines MPI
```

Or add to ipcluster_config.py:

```
c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'MPI'
```

Or just do it manually without any configuration (this is all the above configuration does anyway):

```
mpiexec -n 4 ipengine
```

Comment: You're right. Starting the engines with `ipcluster start -n 2 --engines MPI --profile=mpi` solves the problem. What I was doing before was `ipython profile create --parallel --profile=mpi`, then launching the engines from the IPython dashboard (engines named "MPI" because of the profile, but they are not really MPI engines by default). It works if I add `c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'MPI'` in `ipcluster_config.py`. Anyways, thanks! That was very helpful.